# Merging with git (egit)

Tags: git, merge, egit

i am try my first merge with git (i thought it will be easier with git than with svn - don't know why). At the moment i use egit (eclipse) and it's merge tool.
What i'am missing is the function to tell git that for a given file my local version is the new truth (like copy all from left to right) - i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406144/tfs-compare-in-eclipse-cant-copy-from-left-to-right)

Is there convenient way to overwrite a complete file with my local version? I tried just to save and "add to index" in merge tool but then all the marker "HEAD<<<<<" are also saved :-P. So how to tell merge tool or oher tool "i am fine with left side - take it" (without any change)?

Comment: `git checkout --ours path/to/file`. But then, what's the point of merging if you only use your version?

Comment: this is used only for some files - git detects conflict, i want to merge "nothing" for some files and search for a convenient way to this. It would be fine if i could cover all those use cases with one gui tool. switching the tools for each use case would be a nightmare.

Comment: Do you want to resolve all conflicts in a file with your version, or do you want to have the resulting file to be 100 % identical to your version?

Comment: the latter - want overwrite complete file

Comment: For egit, see the answer on [How to do an “ours” merge using the Eclipse git merge tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11683928/112968)

Comment: thanks in meantime i found out myself this is working: "So when the left section is already good, just make a small modification, undo it and then save. The modification is necessary because save is not available from the beginning." - if you create an answer with it i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, is to use your (`ours`) side of the merge for the complete file. With command line Git this can be done via `git checkout --ours -- path/to/file`.

With *egit* the question [How to do an “ours” merge using the Eclipse git merge tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11674950/112968) has the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11683928/112968) (credits go to [robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst)):

> In the editor of the merge tool, you can edit the left section.
>
> After clicking on Merge Tool, select the "HEAD" option in the dialog
>   that appears, then the left section will contain the same content as
>   HEAD.
>
> So when the left section is already good, just make a small
>   modification, undo it and then save. The modification is necessary
>   because save is not available from the beginning.